# setting env variable like "key=value as string array" in docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, asp.net-core-webapi, appsettings

I want to change settings value in environment section.  like below...

```
environment:
  - GROUP__One=["Group A", "Group B", "Group C"]
```

but it not work. Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that.
You can only set string environment value on docker compose file.

The way to resolve this is to do it inside your code.

For example:

```
environment:
  - GROUP__One=Group A,Group B,Group C
```

On your code, split the environment by `,`

example on Go:

```
strings.Split(os.Getenv("GROUP__One", ","))
```

You can write the seperator other than `,`

Comment: Okay, I will try this way. Thank you, David.